# Magento adding multiple add to cart buttons to catalog page

Tags: magento, button, shopping-cart

We are trying to create a website similar to this one (https://www.hotcha.co.uk/c/21/main) in Magento.  The main thing we are trying to achieve is the multiple Add to Cart buttons within the catalog list page.

Is this even possible in Magento?
If anybody could shed a little light on this for me it would be most appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adapting the Related Products Manager extension.
More info: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/related-proudcts-manager-7301.html

Comment: I'm sure this is possible without using this extension, I have tried deleteting the ctalogvisibility tag in Related.phtml and trying to display related products block in the list.phtml page but this does not work.  Any help anybody?